# Trigonometric anti derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

1. The question is the top integral ,I did substitution of 1+cos ,x+sin2x,sin,cos all of these not works, and I separate them out into two pieces and I am stuck in a new antiderivative :x /(1+cosx)²[image]

\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\dx}{\; \mathrm{d}x}
\int \frac{x+\sin^2x}{(1+\cos x)^2} \dx 
&=\int \frac{x+(1-\cos^2x)}{(1+\cos x)^2} \dx \\
&=\int \frac{x}{(1+\cos x)^2} \dx + \int \frac{1-\cos^2x}{(1+\cos x)^2} \dx \\
&=\int \frac{x}{(1+\cos x)^2} \dx + \int \frac{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}{(1+\cos x)^2} \dx
\end{align*}

Comment: I think what you tried(intentional or not) was to take partial fractions, but when you do partial fractions you don't take $2$ integrals and the denominator should be the same.

Comment: @Ajay The partial fraction is right, I just did some cancellations,

Comment: But where does the other integral come from then? Integration by parts? But even by parts you don't multiply two integrals...I am confused.

Comment: @Ajay bro I just updated the picture, which shows my cancellations

Comment: Oh I see, there was a plus sign in the original photo. I should also mention that you should learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of using a photo as it was hard for me to understand your handwriting.

Comment: @Ajay my bad bro,  ignoring many pieces hard for others to understand

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak, much clearer now.

Comment: I have tried to retype the text from your picture - please, check it and edit it further. (For many reasons, it is better not to use images for math content.) For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using integration by parts gives
$$
     \int \dfrac{x}{(1 + \cos x)^2}dx = xv - \int v dx + C
$$
where $v$ is an anti-derivative of $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{(1 + \cos x)^2}dx$ and $C$ is a constant

Notice that, $1 + \cos x = 2\cos^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$. Hence
$$
       \int \dfrac{1}{(1 + \cos x)^2}dx = \int \dfrac{dx}{4\cos^4 \frac{x}{2}} = \dfrac{1}{4}\int \left[1 + \tan^2 \left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\right]^2 dx
$$
From here, let $t = \tan\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$ and you'll be able to find $v$

Comment: Alternatively, in the last step, use that $(1 + \tan^2 t)^2 = (\tan^2 t + 1) \sec^2 t$ and make an appropriate $u$-substitution.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is a product of an algebraic and a trigonometric function, so the [ILATE mnemonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule) suggests integrating by parts, i.e. using the integration identity $$\int u\,dv = uv - \int v\,du ,$$ with
$$u = x, \qquad dv = \frac{dx}{(1 + \cos x)^2} .$$

Integrating $dv$ gives

$$v = \int dv = \int \frac{dx}{(1 + \cos x)^2} .$$

One option (of many) for evaluating this latter integral is applying the so-called Weierstrass substitution, $$x = 2 \arctan t, \qquad dx = \frac{2\,dt}{1 + t^2} ,$$ which transforms the integral to
$$\frac{1}{2} \int (t^2 + 1) \,dt .$$